# Printing 3 digits in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

This is my printing function, it should output a 3digit result. I store my result in RES which is a dw. The push and pop fixed my problems with printing before now I don't know where it goes wrong.

```
XOR AX, AX
XOR BX, BX

    ;this divides my 3digit number by 100 giving me my, hundredth digit
MOV AX, RES
MOV BX, 100
DIV BX

    ;prints the hundredth digit
ADD AL, '0'
MOV DL, AL
PUSH AX ; save AX on the stack 
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h
POP AX ; restore ax

    ;divides the remainder by 10 giving me my tens digit
MOV BX, 10
DIV BX

    ;prints my tens digit
ADD AL, '0'
MOV DL, AL
PUSH AX ; save AX on the stack
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h
POP AX ; restore ax

    ;print my last remainder which is my ones
ADD AH, '0'
MOV DL, AH
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21h
```

Comment: Sorry but I won't read non-commented assembly. Those comments are useless. You should comment on what the algorithm does, not what the instructions do. Instructions are already documented. Your program is not.

Comment: What result are you getting when you run your code?

Comment: Random letters and would always say, "divide overflow"

Comment: Ok, give us some sample output.  Off hand, it looks like you are dividing by 100 and taking the result and converting to a char, then doing the same for 10, then taking the high 8-bits (remainder) for the last number.  First, this won't work with numbers bigger than 999, second negative will break it, but this is fine.  So off hand it looks "OK", but I would want to see the program and its output to be sure.

Comment: Look at the code where you say you are dividing the remainder by 10. What is the value of `ax` expected to be at this point, which is what you are dividing by 10? (and clear the `dx` as others have suggested)

Comment: You need to clear `dx`, since `div bx` divides `dx:ax` by `bx`. Also, you should save `ax` (i.e. the quotient) _before_ adding `'0'` to it, for the next division to generate a proper result.

Comment: 23 + 43 = 0 divide overflow, 86-81 = -c divide overflow

Comment: I think you need to review the documentation for the `div` instruction (how it works) and also check when you do your `ax` save (push) which seems not to always be saving what you want to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"div bx" divides dx:ax by bx. So, what is your dx?

Comment: This too - forgot about dx myself :)

Comment: Clearing the dx first works with the divide overflow. I am now reading more about the div function :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are taking the address of "RES" instead of its value, which needs a parenthesis or bracket.

Answer (score 0):

At the tens stage your remainder is in AH, not AX.

And **NEVER** put comments like "Save AX on the stack" or "Restore AX".  Anyone with any fluency in assembler (and it's been 20 years since I've written anything in it, yet that includes me) will know what those instructions are doing.

Comments should be explaining *WHY* you are doing it, not what you are doing.

I'm rusty enough on this that I won't swear that there aren't more bugs, I'm just pointing out one I see.